# Calling a servlet filter wrapper in another filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Incorporate an external filter in the servlet web app by creating a wrapper filter.

A third party filter needs to be included in my application and needs to be invoked /bypassed dynamically depending on some logic. I have created a wrapper filter for the `ThirdpartyFilter`, but not sure how to invoke this from the wrapper class

```
final class ThirdPartyFilter implements Filter{

@Override
public void init(@SuppressWarnings("hiding") FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
   this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException  {
    // Some validations here and then call the next filter in the  chain
    }
}

class MyWrapperFilter implements Filter
{

    private ThirdPartyFilter thirdPartyFilter 

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        thirdPartyFilter  = new ThirdPartyFilter(); 
        // Not sure if this is the right way to instantiate the filter
    }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException  
   {
       if(thirdPartyfilterFlag == true) {
          thirdPartyFilter.doFilter(request, response)
       }
       else
       {
           filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
       }
   }
}
```

The issue I am facing is instantiating the ThridPartyFilter from the wrapper.

What's the right way to instantiate this filter ?

Comment: I'm not sure if  it's the right way to instantiate the ThirdPartyFilter, as  the filter configs are usually taken care by the container..

Comment: rather than instantiating a filter from within the wrapper filter add the filter to the filter chain directly through web.xml and check if the filter should be applied or not from within the ThirdPartyFilter filter and not from within the wrapper

Comment: from where are you receiving thirdPartyfilterFlag inside the wrapper filter?

Comment: see this [site](https://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial) - it talks about chaining filters

Comment: @LalitMehra Adding the ThirdPartyFilter to web.xml works fine, but I would not be able to control it unless I wrap it. Depending on the thirdPartyfilterFlag (that's my logic  to determine if filter needs to be invoked) I should be able to able to invoke/bypass the thirdparty filter

Comment: @technoJ I understand that part that's why I asked from where you are getting that flag because if you are able to receive it in some parameter then you can access it in the ThirdPartyFilter as well

Comment: It's not any method parameter, I can call a static method to achieve this

Comment: @technoJ then you can access that parameter in the ThirdPartyFilter itself and do the processing based on it. This will decouple the two filters.

Comment: As the name suggest, it's third party filter.  I don't have the privilege to edit the source code for this..

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if it's the right way to instantiate the
>   ThirdPartyFilter, as the filter configs are usually taken care by the
>   container..

`FilterConfig` just gives you to access the configuration setting you defined in the `<filter>` section in `web.xml` for that filter such that you can access these setting right after the container initialises that Filter.

But now you are programatically instantiating `ThirdPartyFilter` which means you are in total control of  how to create it. It is just a matter if you want to externalise the configuration of `ThirdPartyFilter` to `MyWrapperFilter` 's `<filter>` section in `web.xml`. If not , you can always pass the configuration parameter through the constructor of `ThirdPartyFilter` when creating it.

So I don't see any problems of your codes provided that you initialises `ThirdPartyFilter` correctly. Just a matter of whether you want to externalise its configuration (if it has) to `web.xml`